# Как запустить два js скрипта в travis одновременно?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, travis

Есть два скрипта - тесты и сервер. Тесты не запускают сервер, а просто обращаются по определенному http-адресу через "chai-http", запускаются командой yarn test. Сервер nodejs в свою очередь запускается отдельно командой yarn start, и ждет запросы. Конфиг Travis CI (.travis.yml) имеет вид:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "4"
before_script:
  - yarn install
script:
  - yarn start
  - yarn test
```

При пуше в репозиторий запускается yarn start, открывает порт и ожидает запросы, и дальше команда yarn test не выполняется. Каким образом распараллелить эти две команды?

Comment: запустить yarn start в бэкграунде

Comment: @etki какой командой я могу это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800968/how-can-i-start-and-stop-a-background-task-on-travis https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1321

Answer (score 0):

Подставил амперсант & после команды yarn start - оказалось, что так Travis запускает процесс в фоновом режиме.

```
...
script:
  - yarn start &
  - yarn test
```

В конце сборки автоматически этот процесс убивает:

/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 156:  2923 Terminated              yarn start